# can't write string in the log file using the module log4js

Tags: node.js

I want to write log in the log file using the module `log4js`.

```
const log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: { cheese: { type: "file", filename: "logs/cheese.log" } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ["cheese"], level: "error" } }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');

logger.info("test string");
```

I run the code above. It only create the log file without any text inside. What is wrong?

Comment: I would think that if you have the level set to `error` then only `logger.error` and `logger.fatal` will be written to the file. Try to set the level to `info` or `debug`.

Comment: @Molda You are a genius! That's right.